# Can't click button directly using TestStack.White

Tags: c#, automation, white-framework

I'm trying to click a button on an external windows application. The following code successfully finds the element, brings the parent window into focus and then "manually" clicks the button

This works okay...

```
Process tProcess = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(x => x.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith("MainWindowName"));
if (tProcess != null)
{
    TestStack.White.Application application = TestStack.White.Application.Attach(tProcess.Id);
    var tWindow = application.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("SubWindowName"), InitializeOption.NoCache);
    SearchCriteria searchCriteria = SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("btnCalibrate");
    var calibrateBtn = tWindow.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.Button>(searchCriteria);
    tWindow.Focus();
    var clickablePoint = calibrateBtn.AutomationElement.GetClickablePoint();
    Mouse.Instance.Click(clickablePoint);
}
```

The problem with this is that `Mouse.Instance.Click(clickablePoint);` moves the cursor, ideally I don't want the cursor moved.

My initial code tried to click the button directly using the following

```
Process tProcess = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(x => x.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith("MainWindowName"));
if (tProcess != null)
{
    TestStack.White.Application application = TestStack.White.Application.Attach(tProcess.Id);
    var tWindow = application.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("SubWindowName"), InitializeOption.NoCache);
    SearchCriteria searchCriteria = SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("btnCalibrate");
    var calibrateBtn = tWindow.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.Button>(searchCriteria);
    tWindow.Focus();
    calibrateBtn.Click();
}
```

but this gives the following error every time

```
TestStack.White.AutomationException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Cannot perform action on Button. AutomationId:btnCalibrate, Name:Calibrate, ControlType:button, FrameworkId:WinForm, 
  Source=TestStack.White
  StackTrace:
   at TestStack.White.UIItems.UIItem.PerformIfValid(Action action) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\89a20b30302799e\src\TestStack.White\UIItems\UIItem.cs:line 254
   at TestStack.White.UIItems.UIItem.Click() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\89a20b30302799e\src\TestStack.White\UIItems\UIItem.cs:line 231
   at BetfairStreamingAPI.RadForm1.radLabelBetTime_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:
```

Does anyone know why the second method is throwing this error and if it's possible to fix this so that the button can be clicked without manually moving the cursor?

Edit: Screenshot of attempt to set togglestate

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this particular problem appears to be use `.RaiseClickEvent()` instead of `.Click()`

The following code works

```
Process tProcess = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(x => x.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith("MainWindowName"));
if (tProcess != null)
{
    TestStack.White.Application application = TestStack.White.Application.Attach(tProcess.Id);
    var tWindow = application.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("SubWindowName"), InitializeOption.NoCache);
    SearchCriteria searchCriteria = SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("btnCalibrate");
    var calibrateBtn = tWindow.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.Button>(searchCriteria);

    calibrateBtn.RaiseClickEvent();
}
```

It's not entirely clear from the White docs when/why this is preferred. I found method RaiseClickEvent this on this link  https://github.com/TestStack/White/commit/7b6d4dbc0008c3375e2ebf8810c55cb1abf91b60

Comment: Yep, that's the way to do it. It says so here too
https://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AdvancedTopics/MouseAndKeyboard/

Answer (score 1):

EDIT2

I think you might have found something interesting. Since your button state is Indeterminate, it could be worth turning it on before clicking it:

`calibrateBtn.State = ToggleState.On;`

EDIT1
Alright, let's sort this out together.

There are only two reasons for that action to fail:

1. The button is not enabled, which I guess can't be the case
2. The button is OffScreen

If you do something like

```
Console.WriteLine(calibrateBtn.IsOffScreen.ToString());
```

You should see

```
true
```

If so, try this before you click it:

```
var pattern = calibrateBtn.AutomationElement.GetCurrentPattern(System.Windows.Automation.InvokePattern.Pattern);
(pattern as System.Windows.Automation.InvokePattern).Invoke();
```

Comment: That is the parent window so brings the window to the foreground. It still does not work with this removed.

Comment: IsOffscreen = false. I've also added your recommendation but get the same error. The property calibrateBtn.State = Indeterminate if that means anything, I also tried bringing parent into focus first before getting the button but same error. It's weird as the button is the right one and found but just keeps giving error on click.

Comment: thanks, I added a new edit. Let me know if there are any problems with the code and if it works.

Comment: It won't allow that either. See added screenshot to question -  I get `System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: I think I've found a way to make it work  - `calibrateBtn.RaiseClickEvent();` works! Found this option here  https://github.com/TestStack/White/commit/7b6d4dbc0008c3375e2ebf8810c55cb1abf91b60

Comment: Thumb up, thanks for sharing. Actually you could post your last comment as an answer and accept it, so it will be easier for everybody to find this solution and the question can be closed. Good job!